# Get custom view by tag?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, iphone

У меня есть кастомный класс, в котором описано вью, наследник от UIView. В контроллере, в Методе_Б я создаю в цикле несколько вью и присваеваю им таг.

```
     [array enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id  _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) { 
CustomView *view = [CustomView alloc] init];
view.tag = idx + 100;
}];
```

Далее в Методе_А мне надо получить это созданное вью используя таг. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если все вью добавлены в иерархию, то можно рекурсивно искать среди всех сабвью данного вью:

```
[self.view viewWithTag:index];
```

Comment: Спасибо! Оба варианта работают, выбрал этот, так как короче!

Answer (score 0):

Самый просто способ:

```
-(void)methodAGetViewFromArray:(NSArray *)array {
  for (CustomView *view in array){
      if (view.tag == TAGTHATYOUNEED){
          // TODO SOMETHING
      }
  }
}
```